# Referencing support libraries in xamarin.android solution projects

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I made library that contains some custom components and activities. For this purpose I use some android support libraries. But when I referenced my components library in main application project I must also referenced all external libraries (android support libraries, Zxing and etc) which I used in my components library. Otherwise my application will stop running.
Is it normal behaviour or I made some mistake in libraries referencing? Thx

EDIT:
I forgot to write that I have one solution with these two projects. One project is the main application and second project that is linked to solution is custom components project. I thought that is not necessary referenced all third-party libraries from components project to main project.

Comment: Can you name the libraries you are talking about?

Comment: For example Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat which I installed via nuget package

Comment: Well there are many libraries for android that are essential for android compatibility and yes you going on the right path